# Convolving an image with kernel returns empty image

Tags: python, image-processing, convolution, opencv

I took on a challenge to implement a few OpenCV functions on my own in Python. Very many of these functions require convolving an image with a kernel, so this is the function I wrote to do that:

```py
def convolve(img, kernel):  # img should have zero padding 
    kx, ky = kernel.shape  # kernel is square so kx == ky
    start, end = floor(kx / 2), ceil(kx / 2)
    x, y = img.shape
    convolved = np.zeros((x, y))

    for i in range(kx, x - kx):
        for j in range(kx, y - kx):
            convolved_area = img[i - start:i + end, j - start:j + end] * kernel
            convolved[i][j] = np.sum(convolved_area)

    return convolved
```

When I ran this on an image and a kernel that I made, I received a white image with the only color being the black padding.

For testing, the kernel that I used was a Gaussian kernel:

```py
for x in range(radius):
    for y in range(radius):     # Generate kernel with formula
        kernel[x][y] = exp( -0.5 * (pow((x-mean)/sigma, 2.0) + pow((y-mean)/sigma,2.0)) ) / (2 * pi * sigma * sigma)
        magnitude += kernel[x][y]

for x in range(radius):     # normalize kernel
    for y in range(radius):
        kernel[x][y] /= magnitude
```

I know that the kernel works because using OpenCV's `filter2D` function worked for me:

```py
convolved = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel)
```

My question is why doesn't my `convolve` function work?

Comment: just change your image datatype to uint8 as `convolved = np.zeros((x, y),dtype=np.uint8)` or return result as `return convolved.astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: @user8190410 Thanks that worked! Would you mind explaining what that did/why it worked?

Comment: because if your image datatype is float then it should be in range 0 to 1. That's why image was totally white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to specify the datatype of `uint8` for the image at

```
convolved = np.zeros((x, y))
```

making it

```
convolved = np.zeros((x, y), 'uint8')
```

But **I would recommend using the [`np.zeros_like()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros_like.html#numpy-zeros-like) method**, which takes in an array and returns the array filled with zeros, preserving the original datatype of the array so that you won't have to specify `uint8`:

```
convolved = np.zeros_like(img)
```

The above is the most practical, but a few alternatives are

```
convolved = np.zeros((x, y)).astype('uint8')
```

and

```
convolved = np.uint8(np.zeros((x, y))
```